# How to manage the transfer of large Perl environments from one network to another

Tags: perl

I am trying to install a customer's Perl environment on my employer's network. When said customer runs our non-Perl applications, a lot of Perl code gets exercised here and there throughout their (chip-building) flow. During the archive process at the customer site, a significant amount of Perl content (scripts, modules, etc.) gets collected. By the time everything is unpacked on my employer's network, there is a lot to sort out; for example, the PERLLIB environment variable captured at the customer site has over 430 directory entries.

Not surprisingly, my question is more system administrator-related: what would be the best method to verify that the captured Perl environment at the customer site unpacks and runs smoothly on my employer's network? I realize this is a loaded question, but, in essence, making sure the 430+ entries in the PERLLIB environment variable are ordered just right is proving difficult.

After unpacking my customer's environment, I print out the contents of @INC when a Perl script tries to run but fails to find a specific module (this is BY FAR the most common problem). I then grep/find where the module is located in the extracted directory structure and bump it to the beginning of the @INC list.

perl -e "print join($/,@INC);"

I apologize if this is not the best platform to post such a question, but I wasn't sure where else to go for something this complex.

Comment: Maybe [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org) can answer the question? If you decide to post there, don't forget to announce crossposting to prevent unnecessary work.

Comment: Have you considered Docker? https://www.docker.com/why-docker

Comment: Re "*The PERLLIB environment variable captured at the customer site has over 430 directory entries.*", What???? It doesn't really make sense to have more than one. PERL5LIB should be used for installed modules, and `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/...";` by scripts to find modules relative to a script.

Answer (score 1):

The single most valuable thing you could do with your time and for your customer is to reduce the number of entries in `@INC` and `PERL5LIB`. An entry in `@INC` can hold any number of modules, so even a large and complex project does not need to have too many directories to search through.